# Funções wordpress não funcionam via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, plugin

Estou criando um plugin para o Wordpress com um gravador de áudio. Ao clicar em um botão eu preciso chamar uma função de dentro do meu plugin para enviar um e-mail com esse áudio.

Eu não entendi como usar o `do_action()`, nesse caso então estou tentando via AJAX, contudo quando eu faço a requisição via *POST* no arquivo PHP principal do meu plugin as funções do Wordpress não estão funcionando como o `wp_mail()` que estou usando para mandar o e-mail.

Alguém sabe se esse é o comportamento normal do Wordpress? Como posso implementar esse envio de e-mail?

Comment: Você está fazendo um `$_POST` para o arquivo principal do seu plugin e nenhuma função do WP funciona ou é só a `wp_mail()`?

Comment: na verdade Caio era meu Ajax que não estava certo, para trabalhar com ajax no WP é necessario usar o prefixo 'wp_ajax' e eu não estava usando por isso não estava funcionando as funções do WP. Mas agora eu estou com dificuldade em pegar meu arquivo de audio e anexar no email. eu tenho na minha pagina um '<audio src="my.mp3">' mas não sei anexar esse cara no email que eu estou enviando, pois quando eu pego o aquivo com o '$_Files[]' ele vem vazio e não envia o email

Comment: Carlos, você tentou usar o caminho da imagem? algo como `$anexo = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/arquivo.zip'` ?